# Charging cells in series and parallel

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I am looking into a electric vehicle charging system and using a cell that can charge at 1.6 A and a voltage of 4.2 V. Therefore I believe the max power I can expose this cell to while charging is:

P = IV = 1.6 * 4.2 = 6.72 Watts

Would I be correct in thinking that if I were to connect 90 cells in parallel then I could expose this system to:

6.72 * 90 = 605 Watts ?

Would it also be the case that if I connected two of these set of 90 parallel together by a series connection could I expose with system to:

605 * 2 = 1210 Watts ?

Comment: Maybe change your point of view a little. Thinking about power *consumption* may get you further. You almost never "expose a system to power X", but you provide some power source *capable* of supplying X Watts, and the system consumes as much as it needs at any given point in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically it's correct but,
probably you are talking about li-ion cells. 
Please note that algorithm of charging for li-ion cells it's diffrent: 
firstly it's charging at constant current (1-1.6A per cell) and after current is decreasing it's charged with constant voltage (4.2-4.4V per cell) so charging power is variable during this process.

Comment: Thanks for that. At the moment I am just looking into the fundamentals but that is very useful to consider. However in general am I correct in saying that the more cells I connect, the more energy I can supply them in charging no matter the cell configuration?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.